# Remove jagged edges from mask

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv

**Overview:**
We are working on recoloring of object in image. User can define area of recolor by drawing shape on image and that shape would define boundary for coloring algorithm. After drawing shape user can tap inside shape and based on color of the tapped point, application would run flood fill algorithm and flood fill algorithm will obey the boundary of drawn shape.

**Problem statement:**
Mask created from shape has some jagged because slant lines always comes with Jagged edges. so, output image comes up with serrated edges. I want to create smooth edges.

**Detail of How I am doing**

1. User created shape on image by dragging points,
   [image]
2. Created mask based on selected area(you can see clear problem in edges),
   [image]

[image]

3.Output image (Notice edges of shape)
[image]

You can see that output image has serrated edges.

**Tried**
I tried anti-aliasing in mask image but it is also not working. In output it is coming as bad effect.

I have used OpenCV to achieve this. So, solution surrounding would be more helpful.

Comment: you would have to draw anti-aliased (not the mask but when drawing in the output image). Probably you'll have to do that manually. One (easier to code) option might be to draw in some kind of background image and blend the border to your output image.

Comment: In current approach I am giving mask image into floodfill and it produces output image so, I want to know how to detect what to be anti-aliased.

Comment: you could draw the mask anti-aliased and blend each pixel that is between 0 and 255 (exclusive)

Comment: I know how to anti-aliased mask but don't know other part that you mentioned related to blend pixel. could you send some sudo code or link? It would be really helpful.

Comment: After making anti-aliased mask, you could use this method to blend the mask into your image - [copyTo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto)